# Control drag'n'drop does not work in Stetic in Monodevelop 5.7

Tags: ubuntu, monodevelop

I'm trying to use Stetic in the last version of Monodevelop compiled from source. But when I create new GTK# project and try to drag and drop any controls (e.g. `Fixed`) to my window, nothing happen. Looks like there are no controls can be placed to window.

Is there a way I can fix it? Or is it a bug from last releases of monodevelop?

System data:

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04.1
- Monodevelop: 5.7 git:68d98d4, compiled from source
- GTK#: 2.12.10-5
- Mono: 3.2.8

Thanks for your help.